# I need to fetch the relay=hostname.com from the sendmail logs

Tags: text-processing, sendmail, pattern-matching

I need to fetch the

```
relay=sender.hostname.com
```

from the Sendmail log example below.

```
sendmail[0000]: 03O7cddddddd:  from=<user@user.hostname.com>, size=782, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<msgid555555@.hostname.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=sender.hostname.com [10.0.0.73]
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In order to get the best help, I would recommend to be more specific in your question - are you looking to extract the text sting 'relay=hostname.com' automatically (using a regular expression or similar), or something else?

Comment: yes using the regex.

Comment: Could you be specific and edit your post to provide an example of the _desired_ output?

Answer (score 0):

I could do it using the following cmd.

```
grep "from=" mail.log | sed 's/.*relay=//'
```

sort and select the top 10 using the following cmd.

```
grep "from=" mail.log | sed 's/.*relay=//' | sort | uniq -c |sort -nr -k 1 | head -10
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Note that you should be able to avoid the multiple call to pattern matching programs and incorporate everything into one `sed` call, e.g.: `sed '/from=/s/.*relay=//;t;d' mail.log`.  The leading `/from=/` will ensure that the transformation is performed only on lines containing the `from=` pattern (what currently you do with the `grep`) and the `;t;d` will instruct `sed` to skip all lines without that match.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how "selective" your output needs to be (i.e. if the trailing IP address in `[ ... ]` is also to be included), and if there is possible further text on the line, and assuming GNU `awk`, with the 3-parameter `match()` function, the following would also work:

```
awk '/from=/ {if (match($0,/.*(relay=[^[:space:]]+).*/,a)) printf("%s\n",a[1])}' mail.log
```

For the sample input provided, the output is

```
relay=sender.hostname.com
```